# Get Interest Rate by Country

Tags: web-services, rest

I'm having a heck of a time getting data on interest rate. I guess I could scrape a small pile of central bank websites. What would be better is a service I can get central bank interest rate or prime rate info.

Does anyone know of a free resource for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Federal Reserve of St. Louis is a good source. They have an excel interface as well as a Web Services interface. I have used it with the Python API that is provided here https://github.com/zachwill/fred. The general API is here http://api.stlouisfed.org. Hope this helps.